# Actionlink to child action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, action, actionlink

I have called a view from another with `Html.Action` method. I want to call the same action with a parameter Inside the child view, when user click the action link.

When I write this code I get this error message:

```
Html.ActionLink("link", "Configure", new { id = 2 })
```

> The action 'Configure' is accessible only by a child request.

How can i handle this issue?

**Edit:** I'll try to reexplain the issue:

my parent view is ConfigureMethod.cshtml. I call child child view like that:

```
@Html.Action("Configure", "Payment");
```

It goes to this controller and returns actionresult(not partialview) inside ConfigureMethod view:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Configure()
{

}
```

inside configure view i make an action link like that:

```
Html.ActionLink("link", "Configure", new { id = x.Id })
```

It should goes to this controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Configure(int Id)
{

}
```

However when childonly attribute is written it gives error. When I remove this attribute it works but results comes directly, not inside ConfigureMethod view.

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two things I would like to point out,

1. Child actions are only meant to be rendered as PartialView. So decorating with `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute means, this is the action must return `PartialViewResult`.
2. When we are calling ActionLink(), it will generate a link to a View not Partial View. Even if you will not decorate with `[ChildActionOnly]`, then a link to a partial view makes no sense.

So, first decide if you want a View or Partial View and then design accordingly.

Comment: I edited question to clearify issue with regard to your post.

Comment: @mavera, As you have mentioned Html.ActionLink(....) will generate a link like <a href="/link/Configure"/> , on click on the link it will redirect to another page, So the action should not have [ChildAction] attribute. Where as Html.Action(...) will return a view/partial view with in the context of parent view. [ChildAction] means the action can not be triggered directly but with in a parent context.